# Using regex in facet.contains Solr

Tags: regex, solr, facet, faceted-search

I have solr field stored as -

```
record1 --> colorDimension : "Purple|91"
record2 --> colorDimension : "Purple|974|91"
record3 --> colorDimension : "Purple|974"
```

I need to facet on this colorDimension Field in a way such that term contains "Purple" and number "91".

The result I am targeting is -

```
Purple|91 = 2
```

I was looking out for `facet.contains` but did not get any examples that uses regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should expand these while indexing, so that you have a token for `Purple|91` and `Purple|974` separately. Faceting is quick because it can count tokens, without having to run a regex against each one to find the actual value.

You'll probably have to do this in your code, since I don't think you can make the pattern regex tokenizer spit out multiple tokens for a given prefix / group.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this pattern:

```
Purple\|(?:\d+\|)*91(?:\||$)
```

### Demo

Comment: do you have any clue about regex execution in facet.contains in solr?

Comment: @VibhavSinghRohilla Unfortunately I don't.  I assumed that you already had some code with regex, and you only needed help finding a matching pattern.

Comment: Hi @VibhavSinghRohilla, did you find a solution by your own ? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually need to make use of regular expressions, there is a parameter `facet.matches`, which can be used to specify a regular expression to restrict the facet results